# (webview2)How can I get DevToolsProtocolEventReceived message faster than original network in CDP?

Tags: c#, websocket, webview2

I use DevToolsProtocolEventReceived to get "Network.webSocketFrameReceived" in C#. I find webview2 will give me the event after it render the browser, but in original network tool in CDP(F12), websocketframe is recorded before render;

Answer (score 0):

Non-blocking CDP events will always race page rendering or other processing in the WebView2 processes.

All CDP events should be raised in the usual manner in the browser or the DevTools compared to WebView2. But you may have other issues receiving the event in your host app. The event will be sent cross process to the host app and queued in the WebView2 event queue waiting for the WebView2 UI thread to become available to raise the event.  If you have many events occurring at that time, or if you are doing much work on the UI thread of the WebView2, this can all delay the CDP event. You can try to reduce this to receive the event earlier, but it will always be a race between the non-blocking CDP event and whatever is happening in the WebView2 processes.

You can read more about the [WebView2 threading model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/threading-model) and [process model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/concepts/process-model).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have read the threading model. I find that webview UI will first render the websocketframe then trigger the event. Its too late. So how can I get the  Non-blocking CDP events?